# How to map ICollection to Dictionary with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to use automapper for mapping reverse engineered classes from EF Core.
This is a simplified version of the classes I am trying to map:

```
public partial class TblProject
{
    public TblProject()
    {
        TblProjectTranslations = new HashSet<TblProjectTranslation>();
    }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TblProjectTranslation> TblProjectTranslations { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblProjectTranslation
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public virtual TblProject Project { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my destination class:

```
public class Project
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Name { get; set; } = new();
}
```

This is how my mapping profile currently looks like (reverse mapping should also be possible):

```
public ProjectProfile()
{
    CreateMap<TblProject, Project>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectId))
        .ReverseMap();
}
```

I want to map the `ICollection<TblProjectTranslation>` to a dictionary so that the `Language` property becomes the key and the `ProjectName` property becomes the value in the dictionary. I was already able to map from `ICollection<TblProjectTranslation>` to `Dictionary<string, string>` but due to the ProjectId property being ignored in this conversion, I do not know how I can map back from `Dictionary<string, string>` to `ICollection<TblProjectTranslation>`. To do this, I need the project Id but I do not have access to the project in the type converter. How can I do this so it is possible to map in both directions?

Answer (score 0):

I was now already able to figure out a way to implement this with a custom type converter like this:

```
public class TranslationConverter : ITypeConverter<ICollection<TblProjectTranslation>, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Convert(ICollection<TblProjectTranslation> source, Dictionary<string, string> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return new();
        }
        else
        {
            return source.ToDictionary(keySelector: x => x.Language, elementSelector: x => x.ProjectName);
        }
    }
}
```

New mapping profile:

```
public ProjectProfile()
{
    CreateMap<TblProject, Project>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectId))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TblProjectTranslations))
        .ReverseMap();

    CreateMap<ICollection<TblProjectTranslation>, Dictionary<string, string>>()
        .ConvertUsing<TranslationConverter>();
}
```

The only limitation right now is that I cannot map a `Project` back to a `TblProject` with this solution. If anyone knows how to do that, please let me know. Otherwise I will try to figure this out myself and edit the answer accordingly as soon as I found a solution.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create another custom transformation class for reverse mapping like: ReverseTranslationConverter and implement the reverse logic in that new class.

Comment: @ironman Yes, I actually did that already. The problem is that when I convert from the collection into a dictionary, some properties like the project id are ignored. These properties are then missing when I convert back from a dictionary to a collection. Since I have no access to the parent project when implementing a second type converter, I do not know how I can set the id (and other properties which I left out here for simplicity) again in the collection. They are already in my `Project` class but I cannot access the project in the type converter.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I don't understand what you are suggesting. Do you have an example?